# How to parse JSON with variable keys in Scala Play?

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Happy new years, first of all!

I'm having some problem parsing JSON in Play, the format I'm dealing with is as follows:

```
JSON Response:

 ...
"image":{  
    "large":{  
      "path":"http://url.jpg",
      "width":300,
      "height":200
    },
    "medium":{  
      "path":"http://url.jpg",
      "width":200,
      "height":133
    },
    ...
 }
...
```

I'm stuck on the field with the sizes. They are obviously variables, and I'm not sure how to write a formatter for this? The JSON is coming from an external service.

So far I have

```
final case class Foo(
  ..
  ..
  image: Option[Image])


final case class Image(size: List[Size])

final case class Size(path: String, width: Int, height: Int)
```

For the formatting I just did `Json.reads[x]` for all the classes. However I'm pretty sure that the variable for size is throwing off the formatting because it's not able to create an Image object from the JSON coming in.

Comment: Not seeing a way you can use the `reads` macro to do this. Do you want to keep the size descriptors? (large, medium..)

Comment: I know that there are 11 size descriptors and their values. Is there a way to put them in some `Seq(size1, size2, ..., sizeN) -> imageDetails` or something similar?

Comment: What about adding the descriptor to the `Size` class? `Size(name: String, path: String, width: Int, height: Int)`, and then read them into a list? `Image(..., sizes: List[Size])`

Comment: I don't think that would work because in the JSON the size description is not in the object. It's `sizeDescription: { path: "", width: "", height: "" }`

Comment: I'm asking if that's an acceptable structure to convert it to. If so, I can make a more detailed answer. It's definitely possible to read it that way.

Comment: Sorry, yes I can model it that way. I just can't alter the JSON I'm receiving. Thanks

Comment: See my answer for a instance for both reading and writing in terms of play.api.libs.json.Format values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you want deserialize into the following case classes:

```
case class Size(name: String, path: String, width: Int, height: Int)
case class Image(sizes: List[Size])
case class Foo(..., image: Option[Image])
```

There are many ways to make this work via custom `Reads` implementations. I'm going to use the `reads` macro for `Size`:

```
implicit val sizeReads = Json.reads[Size]
```

Then, since the sizes aren't an actual array within the `image` object, I'll just make them into one to take advantage of the `Reads[Size]` I already have. I can transform a given `JsValue` that's being validated as an `Image` into a `JsObject`. I can then grab the `fields` from the `JsObject` which will be a `Seq[(String, JsValue)]`. In this case, the `String` is the size descriptor, and the `JsValue` is the object containing all the values for that size. I'll just merge them together into a single object, and make a `JsArray` out of the `Seq`.

From there, all I need to do is validate that `JsArray` as a `List[Size]`, and `map` it to an `Image`.

```
implicit val imageReads = new Reads[Image] {
    def reads(js: JsValue): JsResult[Image] = {
        val fields: Seq[JsValue] = js.as[JsObject].fields.map { case (name, values) =>
            Json.obj("name" -> name) ++ values.as[JsObject]
        }

        JsArray(fields).validate[List[Size]].map(Image(_))
    }
}
```

Then `Foo` can also use the `reads` macro.

```
implicit val fooReads = Json.reads[Foo]
```

Example:

```
case class Foo(something: String, image: Option[Image])

val json = Json.parse("""{
    "something":"test",
    "image":{  
        "large":{  
            "path":"http://url.jpg",
            "width":300,
            "height":200
        },
        "medium":{  
            "path":"http://url.jpg",
            "width":200,
            "height":133
        }
    }
}""")

scala> json.validate[Foo]
res19: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[Foo] = JsSuccess(Foo(test,Some(Image(List(Size(large,http://url.jpg,300,200), Size(medium,http://url.jpg,200,133))))),)
```

Implementing a `Writes[Image]` is a little easier if you take advantage of `Json.obj` to mimic the structure of the output JSON you want. Since the output JSON doesn't actually use an array, we also need to merge the list of sizes back into a single object, which we can do using `foldLeft`.

```
implicit val writes = new Writes[Image] {
    def writes(img: Image): JsValue = {
        img.sizes.foldLeft(new JsObject(Nil)) { case (obj, size) =>
            obj ++ Json.obj(
                size.name -> Json.obj(
                    "path" -> size.path,
                    "width" -> size.width,
                    "height" -> size.height
                )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey that's a fantastic answer, it makes a lot of sense. I just compiled and found out I need a writer for this as well, because in `class Foo` I have `(__ \ 'image).format[Option[Image]` so I need to be able to write the object to JSON also. I edited my question to include my attempt but it's not working, any pointers on that also? Thanks again for the great response.

Answer (score 8):

## Update 2016-07-28

The solution described below breaks [Referential Transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency) because of the use of the `return` keyword and is not something I would recommend today. Nevertheless, I am not leaving it as it for historical reasons.

## Intro

The issue here is that you need to find someplace to save the key for each `Size` object in the `Image` object. There are two ways to do this, one is to save it in the `Size` object itself. This makes sense because the name is intimately related to the `Size` object, and it is convenient to store it there. So lets explore that solution first.

## A quick note on Symmetry

Before we dive into any solutions, let me first introduce the concept of symmetry. This the idea that when you read any Json value, you can use your Scala model representation to go back to *exactly* the same Json value.

Symmetry when dealing with marshalled data is not strictly required, indeed sometimes it is either not possible, or enforcing it would be too costly without any real gain. But *usually* it is fairly easy to achieve and it makes working with the serialization implementation much nicer. In many cases it is required as well.

## Save `name` in `Size`

```
import play.api.libs.json.Format
import play.api.libs.json.JsPath
import play.api.libs.json.Reads
import play.api.libs.json.JsValue
import play.api.libs.json.JsResult
import play.api.libs.json.JsSuccess
import play.api.libs.json.JsError
import play.api.libs.json.JsObject
import play.api.libs.json.Json

final case class Foo(images: Option[Image])

object Foo {
  implicit val fooFormat: Format[Foo] = Json.format[Foo]
}

final case class Image(sizes: Seq[Size])

object Image {

  implicit val imagesFormat: Format[Image] =
    new Format[Image] {

      /** @inheritdoc */
      override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Image] = json match {
        case j: JsObject => {
          JsSuccess(Image(j.fields.map{
            case (name, size: JsObject) =>
              if(size.keys.size == 3){
                val valueMap = size.value
                valueMap.get("path").flatMap(_.asOpt[String]).flatMap(
                  p=> valueMap.get("height").flatMap(_.asOpt[Int]).flatMap(
                    h => valueMap.get("width").flatMap(_.asOpt[Int]).flatMap(
                      w => Some(Size(name, p, h, w))
                    ))) match {
                  case Some(value) => value
                  case None => return JsError("Invalid input")
                }
              } else {
                  return JsError("Invalid keys on object")
              }
            case _ =>
              return JsError("Invalid JSON Type")
          }))
        }
        case _ => JsError("Invalid Image")
      }

      /** @inheritdoc */
      override def writes(o: Image): JsValue = {
        JsObject(o.sizes.map((s: Size) =>
          (s.name ->
            Json.obj(
              ("path" -> s.path),
              ("height" -> s.height),
              ("width" -> s.width)))))
      }
    }

}

final case class Size(name: String, path: String, height: Int, width: Int)
```

In this solution `Size` does not have any Json serialization or deserialization directly, rather it comes as a product of the `Image` object. This is because, in order to have symmetric serialization of your `Image` object you need to keep not only the parameters of the `Size` object, path, height, and width, but also the `name` of the `Size` as specified as the keys on the `Image` object. If you don't store this you can't go back and forth freely.

So this works as we can see below,

```
scala> import play.api.libs.json.Json
import play.api.libs.json.Json

scala> Json.parse("""
     | {  
     |     "large":{  
     |       "path":"http://url.jpg",
     |       "width":300,
     |       "height":200
     |     },
     |     "medium":{  
     |       "path":"http://url.jpg",
     |       "width":200,
     |       "height":133
     |     }
     | }""")
res0: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"large":{"path":"http://url.jpg","width":300,"height":200},"medium":{"path":"http://url.jpg","width":200,"height":133}}

scala> res0.validate[Image]
res1: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[Image] = JsSuccess(Image(ListBuffer(Size(large,http://url.jpg,200,300), Size(medium,http://url.jpg,133,200))),)

scala>
```

And very importantly it is both *safe* and *symmetric*

```
scala> Json.toJson(res0.validate[Image].get)
res4: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"large":{"path":"http://url.jpg","height":200,"width":300},"medium":{"path":"http://url.jpg","height":133,"width":200}}

scala>
```

## A quick note on Safety

In production code, you never, never, never want to use the `.as[T]` method on a `JsValue`. This is because if the data is not what you expected, it blows up without any meaningful error handling. If you must, use `.asOpt[T]`, but a much better choice in general is `.validate[T]`, as this will produce some form of error on failure that you can log and then report back to the user.

## Probably a Better Solution

Now, probably a better way to do accomplish this would be to change the `Image` case class declaration to the following

```
final case class Image(s: Seq[(String, Size)])
```

and then keep `Size` as you originally had it,

```
final case class Size(path: String, height: Int, width: Int)
```

Then you merely need to do the following to be safe and symmetric.

If we do this then the implementation becomes much nicer, while still being safe and symmetric.

```
import play.api.libs.json.Format
import play.api.libs.json.JsPath
import play.api.libs.json.Reads
import play.api.libs.json.JsValue
import play.api.libs.json.JsResult
import play.api.libs.json.JsSuccess
import play.api.libs.json.JsError
import play.api.libs.json.JsObject
import play.api.libs.json.Json

final case class Foo(images: Option[Image])

object Foo {
  implicit val fooFormat: Format[Foo] = Json.format[Foo]
}

final case class Image(sizes: Seq[(String, Size)])

object Image {

  implicit val imagesFormat: Format[Image] =
    new Format[Image] {

      /** @inheritdoc */
      override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Image] = json match {
        case j: JsObject =>
          JsSuccess(Image(j.fields.map{
            case (name, size) =>
              size.validate[Size] match {
                case JsSuccess(validSize, _) => (name, validSize)
                case e: JsError => return e
              }
          }))
        case _ =>
          JsError("Invalid JSON type")
      }

      /** @inheritdoc */
      override def writes(o: Image): JsValue = Json.toJson(o.sizes.toMap)
    }
}

final case class Size(path: String, height: Int, width: Int)

object Size {
  implicit val sizeFormat: Format[Size] = Json.format[Size]
}
```

Still works as before

```
scala> Json.parse("""
     | {
     | "large":{  
     |       "path":"http://url.jpg",
     |       "width":300,
     |       "height":200
     |     },
     |     "medium":{  
     |       "path":"http://url.jpg",
     |       "width":200,
     |       "height":133}}""")
res1: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"large":{"path":"http://url.jpg","width":300,"height":200},"medium":{"path":"http://url.jpg","width":200,"height":133}}

scala> res1.validate[Image]
res2: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[Image] = JsSuccess(Image(ListBuffer((large,Size(http://url.jpg,200,300)), (medium,Size(http://url.jpg,133,200)))),)

scala> Json.toJson(res1.validate[Image].get)
res3: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"large":{"path":"http://url.jpg","height":200,"width":300},"medium":{"path":"http://url.jpg","height":133,"width":200}}
```

But with the benefit that `Size` is now reflective of real Json, that is you can serialize and deserialize just `Size` values. Which makes it both easier to work with and think about.

### TL;DR Commentary on `reads` in the First Example

Although I would argue that the first solution is somewhat inferior to the second solution, we did use some interesting idioms in the first implementation of `reads` that are very useful, in a more general sense, but often not well understood. So I wanted to take the time to go through them in more detail for those who are interested. If you already understand the idioms in use, or you just don't care, feel free to skip this discussion.

#### `flatMap` chaining

When we attempt to get the values we need out of `valueMap`, at any an all steps things can go wrong. We would like to handle these cases reasonably without catastrophic exceptions being thrown.

To accomplish this we use the `Option` value and common `flatMap` function to chain our computation. There are really two steps we do for each desired value, get the value out of `valueMap` and we force it to the proper type using the `asOpt[T]` function. Now the nice thing is that both `valueMap.get(s: String)` and `jsValue.asOpt[T]` both return `Option` values. This means that we can use `flatMap` to build our final result. `flatMap` has the nice property that if any of the steps in the `flatMap` chain fail, i.e. return `None`, then all other steps are not run and the final result is returned as `None`.

This idiom is part of general *Monadic* programming that is common to functional languages, especially Haskell and Scala. In Scala it is not often referred to as *Monadic* because when the concept was introduced in Haskell it was often explained poorly leading to many people disliking it, despite it in fact being very useful. Due to this, people are often afraid to use the "M word" with respect to Scala.

#### Functional Short Circuiting

The other idiom that is used in `reads`, in both versions, is short circuiting a function call by using the `return` keyword in scala.

As you probably know, use of the `return` keyword is often discouraged in Scala, as the final value of any function is automatically made into the return value for the function. There is however one very useful time to use the `return` keyword, that is when you are calling a function that represents a repeated call over something, such as the `map` function. If you hit some terminal condition on one of the inputs you can use the `return` keyword to stop the execution of the `map` call on the remaining elements. It is somewhat analogous to using `break` in a `for` loop in languages like Java.

In our case, we wanted to ensure certain things about the elements in the Json, like that it had the correct keys and types, and if at any point any of our assumptions were incorrect, we wanted to return the proper error information. Now we could just `map` over the fields in the Json, and then inspect the result after the `map` operation has completed, but consider if someone had sent us *very large* Json with thousands of keys that did not have the structure we wanted. We would have to apply our function to **all** of the values even if we knew we had an error after only the first application. Using `return` we can end the `map` application as soon we know about an error, without having to spend time apply the `map` application across the rest of the elements when the result is already known.

Anyway, I hope that little bit of pedantic explanation is helpful!

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the answer. It's very clean. Also thanks for the tips on `validate` and not using `as`, I hadn't thought of that before. I'm shutting off for the day but will comment some more tomorrow. Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is more normal with basic types. Only we define two classes:

```scala
final case class Size(path: String, width: Int, height: Int)
final case class Image(image: Map[String, Size])

implicit val sizeFormat: Format[Size] = Json.format[Size]
implicit val imageFormat: Format[Image] = Json.format[Image]
```

Then, run an example:

```scala
val json: JsValue = Json.parse("""
{
  "image":{  
    "large":{  
      "path":"http://url.jpg",
      "width":300,
      "height":200
    },
    "medium":{  
      "path":"http://url.jpg",
      "width":200,
      "height":133
    }
  }
}
""")

json.validate[Image]
```

You can get

```
scala> json.validate[Image]
res13: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[Image] = JsSuccess(Image(Map(large -> Size(http://url.jpg,300,200), medium -> Size(http://url.jpg,200,133))),)

scala> json.validate[Image].get.image
res14: Map[String,Size] = Map(large -> Size(http://url.jpg,300,200), medium -> Size(http://url.jpg,200,133))

scala> json.validate[Image].get.image("large")
res15: Size = Size(http://url.jpg,300,200)

scala> json.validate[Image].get.image("large").path
res16: String = http://url.jpg
```

Also you could write:

```
scala> json.validate[Image].get
res18: Image = Image(Map(large -> Size(http://url.jpg,300,200), medium -> Size(http://url.jpg,200,133)))

scala> Json.toJson(json.validate[Image].get)
res19: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"image":{"large":{"path":"http://url.jpg","width":300,"height":200},"medium":{"path":"http://url.jpg","width":200,"height":133}}}
```